# Require at least 4" display

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm building an Xcode app, and realized that it won't work on any devices that have a 3.5" screen, due to some interface elements I'd rather not change.

Is there any way I can register this requirement with iTunes Connect or some other way to prevent users from downloading the app on a 3.5" device?

I could check the screen size on load and just display a message to the user instead of loading my app, but I'd rather not have people disappointed when they download my app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You may even get rejected if you don't make your app accessible to users with a 3.5" screen.

Comment: Thanks. Adjusted my app so it works with 3.5 inch now, didn't even think to make a separate view controller.

Comment: I would have said "You will very probably get rejected" instead of "You may even get rejected": unless the reviewer didn't notice it would surely be rejected. Furthermore, screenshots for 3.5" devices are a must, so there is no way you can send the version unless you tweaked the screenshots for 3.5" devices.